# Nextjs Shadcn form, react-hook-form, zod resolver not submitting on click

Tags: typescript, forms, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm having issues with a form using Shadcn, React Hook Form, and Zod resolver. The code isn't entering the onSubmit function when clicking the submit button, and nothing happens. I've tried everything, changing Next.js versions, Shadcn versions, etc., but the issue persists. Below, I provide the code:

```
const formSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, {
    message: "Name is required.",
  }),
  description: z.string().min(1, {
    message: "Description is required.",
  }),
  instructions: z.string().min(200, {
    message: "Instructions require at least 200 characters."
  }),
  seed: z.string().min(200, {
    message: "Seed requires at least 200 characters."
  }),
  src: z.string().min(1, {
    message: "Image is required."
  }),
  categoryId: z.string().min(1, {
    message: "Category is required",
  }),
});

interface CharacterFormProps {
  categories: Category[];
  initialData: Character | null;
};

export const CharacterForm = ({
  categories,
  initialData
}: CharacterFormProps) => {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const router = useRouter();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: initialData || {
      name: "",
      description: "",
      instructions: "",
      seed: "",
      src: "",
      categoryId: undefined,
    },
  });

  const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      console.log("Entrando a onSubmit")
      if (initialData) {
        await axios.patch(`/api/character/${initialData.id}`, values);
      } else {
        await axios.post("/api/character", values);
      }

      toast({
        description: "Success.",
        duration: 3000,
      });

      router.refresh();
      router.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        variant: "destructive",
        description: "Something went wrong.",
        duration: 3000,
      });
    }
  };

  return ( 
    <div className="h-full p-4 space-y-2 max-w-3xl mx-auto">
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8 pb-10">
          <div className="space-y-2 w-full col-span-2">
            <div>
              <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">General Information</h3>
              <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                General information about your Character
              </p>
            </div>
            <Separator className="bg-primary/10" />
          </div>
          <FormField
            name="src"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-4 col-span-2">
                <FormControl>
                  <ImageUpload disabled={isLoading} onChange={field.onChange} value={field.value} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
            <FormField
              name="name"
              control={form.control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="col-span-2 md:col-span-1">
                  <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input disabled={isLoading} placeholder="Elon Musk" {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>
                    This is how your AI Character will be named.
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              name="description"
              control={form.control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Description</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input disabled={isLoading} placeholder="CEO &apos; Founder of Tesla, SpaceX" {...field} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>
                    Short description for your AI Character
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="categoryId"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Category</FormLabel>
                  <Select disabled={isLoading} onValueChange={field.onChange} value={field.value} defaultValue={field.value}>
                    <FormControl>
                      <SelectTrigger className="bg-background">
                        <SelectValue defaultValue={field.value} placeholder="Select a category" />
                      </SelectTrigger>
                    </FormControl>
                    <SelectContent>
                      {categories.map((category) => (
                        <SelectItem key={category.id} value={category.id}>{category.name}</SelectItem>
                      ))}
                    </SelectContent>
                  </Select>
                  <FormDescription>
                    Select a category for your AI
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="space-y-2 w-full">
            <div>
              <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Configuration</h3>
              <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                Detailed instructions for AI Behaviour
              </p>
            </div>
            <Separator className="bg-primary/10" />
          </div>
          <FormField
            name="instructions"
            control={form.control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Instructions</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Textarea disabled={isLoading} rows={7} className="bg-background resize-none" placeholder={PREAMBLE} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>
                  Describe in detail your companion&apos;s backstory and relevant details.
                </FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="seed"
            control={form.control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Example Conversation</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Textarea disabled={isLoading} rows={7} className="bg-background resize-none" placeholder={SEED_CHAT} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>
                  Write couple of examples of a human chatting with your AI character, write expected answers.
                </FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <div className="w-full flex justify-center">
            <Button size="lg" disabled={isLoading}>
              {initialData ? "Edit your companion" : "Create your companion"}
              <Wand2 className="w-4 h-4 ml-2" />
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </div>
   );
};

export default CharacterForm;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The onSubmit function will only run when the data is valid - do you have missing fields when you hit Submit?

Comment: Hello, yes, the input fields are always filled, and it's supposed to be exactly as it appears in the code; if I don't fill in any field, an alert should be displayed. That also doesn't happen. The code seems not to be working.

Comment: I'm also having that problem. I'm filling out the form according to the schema yet it seems like there's still an error in form with some field.